# post increment of a variable

Tags: java, operators

can anyone explain me why do i get

```
error: unexpected type
  System.out.println("PostFixOperators for b with addition of a "+b++ +=a);
  required: variable
  found:    value
```

at compile time when i run this code.

```
public class PostFixOperators {
         static int a, b ;
        public static void main(String arv[]) {
            System.out.println("PostFixOperators for a "+ a++);
            System.out.println("PostFixOpearators for b with addition of a "+b++ +=a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is not valid Java syntax. What was your intention with a statement like this? It's unclear why you would want to write something like `"..."+b++ +=a`

Comment: You can't call `+=a` on `b++`, because `b++` isn't a variable - it's the old value of `b` before `b` was incremented.

Comment: Store your value of `a++` in variable `a` and do the same with b then jus print it out.

Answer (score 0):

`b++ += a` will not compile because `b++` is not a variable. It is just the value of `b` before the increment.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the x= operators (like +=, *=, ...) and so on are just a shortcut.

Like:

a += 5;

Means:

a = a + 5;

In other words: you need *something* on the left hand side of that operator that you can **assign** a value to. But "b++" is not such a thing. Because it is not a variable (any more):

"b++" is an expression that returns a *value*. (in contrast to ++b!)

You can't assign values to values!

Comment: postfix operators are values while

Answer (score 0):

```
int i, x;

i = 2;
x = ++i;
// now i = 3, x = 3

i = 2;
x = i++; 
// now i = 3, x = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't not assign value to the variable in printing statements.

Because here the question raise is what should be print on the screen.

Does it new value of a variable or
Does it true or false indicating that assignment done successfully..

So you can do like this..

a+= b++;
System.out.println("PostFixOpearators for b with addition of a "+ a);

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only use assignment operators on variables.

1. `b` is a variable
2. `b++` is a Unary Operation

However the following statement may be of some use to you.

```
System.out.println("PostFixOpearators for b with addition of a " + (b = b++ + a));
```

*P.S.: There would be no use of using PostFix in above code because the value would be overridden when assignment is done. However, you may use it when you encounter a situation where you need to use PreFix in a similar fashion.*